# Participation for the main site

Tags: discussion, feature-request, users

When we are in meta and we click on user, we can sort them by participation. According to the description, it measures the activity.

I suggest to make something similar for the main site, for example based on the total activity (answers, comments, edits, asked questions, reviews). We could for example display that in a disk with colors associated with each kind of activity. Then the existing section "Editors" will be contained in "Activity", like the other types.

"Activity" as defined before is, to my mind, like reputation, a good way to have an idea about the contribution of an user to the site.

What do you think?

Comment: Could be interesting! What kind of weights should we have for each type of activity? A percentage figure (in comparison to the highest number) for each type of activity?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes for example (with the total number of actions).

Comment: Why would we want to do this?

Comment: @Chris: Curiosity?

Comment: @ChrisEagle Curiosity, like for reputation, editors, voters, etc...

Comment: How is "activity" measured on meta?  I always assumed it was just using the secret meta reputation count, so on the main site would just agree with reputation.

Comment: @NoahSnyder: Indeed, it would be good to know.

Comment: @NoahSnyder No, it's not the hidden rep counter. Hovering over the word `participation` brings up the text "Users most active on this site in the last 60 days (combined number of posts, votes, comments and edits)". [Meta.SO source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149097)

Answer (score 5):

The link to list of users ordered by participation is `http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation`: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation

If you simply remove `meta.` part from the URL, you get this list: https://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation

I'd guess that it is calculated by the same algorithm as on meta, so it might be what you want. However, there is not a separate tab for this on the main, you have to modify the URL manually.

Comment: Ooh, another hidden feature. I like those. There is a meta.SO thread that collects them, but I don't remember seeing this one there.

Comment: I did not know about the [list of hidden features](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-exchange/). Thanks for letting me know, I posted this "hidden feature" as an answer there.